# Blender GIS convert 3d model to Mesh

Tags: modelling

The GIS model that shows in Layout (Export_Google_Sat_WM).

Can it be Sculpted?

I can't seem to see it in any other viewport like modeling, or sculpting. It can only be viewed in Layout. I have watched and read many videos and threads but can't seem to get a good end result or answer. I have tried export and importing the file in fxb, obj to get a new mesh that is editable with no luck.

How can I convert the GIS model into a workable mesh?

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest you ask at https://blender.stackexchange.com/ but make sure you show a basic understanding of how Blender works and what you tried (and why) so people know what level of help you need.

Comment: lol a lot! I posted their first.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 0):

Just export it and then it can be editable 3d model